# Espresso testing disable animation

Tags: android, animation, android-testing, android-espresso

[image]

```
@Test
    public void test3_PaySuccessful(){
        init();

    ViewInteraction amountEditText = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.et_amount), isDisplayed()));
    amountEditText.perform(replaceText("SGD 0.010"), closeSoftKeyboard());

    //, withText("Proceed")
    ViewInteraction appCompatButton = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.btn_confirm), isDisplayed()));
    appCompatButton.perform(click());

    //, withText("Pay")
    ViewInteraction appCompatButton2 = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.btn_confirm), isDisplayed()));
    appCompatButton2.perform(click());

    //dialog
    ViewInteraction appCompatButton3 = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.confirm_button), withText("Confirm"), isDisplayed()));
    appCompatButton3.perform(click());

    //have to disable animation in order to pass this.
    intended(CoreMatchers.allOf(hasComponent(PaymentSelectionActivity2.class.getName())));

}
```

I encountered an issue on doing Espresso testing with a view involving animation, I know Espresso cannot deal with animation, so i did below.
- disable my test device Window animation, transition animation and animator duration scale all set to OFF (this does not work)
- then i tried to add a flag in my code eg. espresso_testing = true. if true, my code will skip calling all startAnimation() function call. ---> this is working. However, there is a requirement that I cannot change code on my app while writing espresso test case. Included a test case above.

Is there any other way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this. it very fast https://stackoverflow.com/a/56198539/4797289

Answer (score 100):

**Make sure to keep your plugin updated:**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
  }
}
```

**Use the new flag in `testOptions` called `animationsDisabled`:**

```
android {

  ...

  testOptions {
    animationsDisabled = true
  }
}
```

**Source:** https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions:animationsDisabled

**You can try turning off animations on your device/emulator manually:**

> To avoid flakiness, we highly recommend that you turn off system
>   animations on the virtual or physical devices used for testing. On
>   your device, under Settings > Developer options, disable the following
>   3 settings:
>
> Window animation scale Transition animation scale Animator duration
>   scale

**Source:** https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup#set-up-environment

**You can try using `adb` via command line:**

```
# Turn off animations
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
```

**Source:** https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gif-example/blob/master/.travis.yml#L34

**You can try LinkedIn's `TestButler`:**

```
TestButler.verifyAnimationsDisabled(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
```

**Source:** https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler/blob/master/test-butler-demo/src/androidTest/java/com/linkedin/android/testbutler/demo/AnimationDisablerTest.java#L26

**You can try creating a `TestRule` and `Gradle` task for your espresso tests:**

**Source:** https://product.reverb.com/disabling-animations-in-espresso-for-android-testing-de17f7cf236f

Comment: I am using a real device for testing, does the above still apply?

Comment: @kggoh You can try the Android DSL `animationsDisabled`, the second one may or may not work. I use it on API 19 emulators.

Comment: animationsDisabled is unknown property and i did add the buildscript you stated above

Comment: `animationsDisabled` is not an unknown property. I just pointed you to the official documentation. You have to have the latest android plugin `2.3.1`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows, have you tested `animationsDisabled` flag on your own or are you just relying on documentation? Personally I am unable to make use of that flag,

Comment: @azizbekian I relied on documentation but I try to use all techniques. If you are using Spoon or TestButler, you can toggle off animations as well.

Comment: For others: `animationsDisabled` is equivalent of `am instrument --no-window-animation` for running tests and `adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0` before running tests. To disable all animations run all three `adb shell ...` commands from above answer before running tests. Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69247502

Comment: Do these settings apply to Lottie animations? Seems like some of our Lottie animations continue to run in UI tests.

Comment: `animationsDisabled` doesn't work according to http://myhexaville.com/2018/01/15/android-espresso-testing/ and according to my experience just now with gradle-5.1.1-all.zip and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.

Comment: Note the documentations says ["This property does not affect tests that you run using Android Studio."](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/TestOptions#animationsdisabled)

Comment: @Michael Osofsky True, but starting from Android Studio Bumblebee instrumented tests are executed via Gradle test runner

Answer (score 7):

***You have three different options to choose from:***

**1. Use this in Gradle**

```
android {

  //...

  testOptions {
    animationsDisabled = true
  }

  // ...
}
```

**2. Use in ADB for device**

```
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
```

**3. Use the Rule**

```
class DisableAnimationsRule : TestRule {
    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
           override fun evaluate() {
                // disable animations for test run
                changeAnimationStatus(enable = false)
                try {
                    base.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    // enable after test run
                    changeAnimationStatus(enable = true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun changeAnimationStatus(enable:Boolean = true) {
        with(UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())){
            executeShellCommand("settings put global transition_animation_scale ${if(enable) 1 else 0}")
            executeShellCommand("settings put global window_animation_scale ${if(enable) 1 else 0}")
            executeShellCommand("settings put global animator_duration_scale ${if(enable) 1 else 0}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you list points makes it look like one **has to** do all those steps to disable animations but in fact they are all alternative of each other. That is why adding description is helpful

Answer (score 5):

True, you shouldn't add test code in production code. The problem here lies in the animation. If you are performing animations using `Handlers` and `Runnables` then you can't turn them off using the Developer Options. A common place where we use this to animate is in Custom views.

But even in custom views, ensure you use either `ValueAnimator`, `ObjectAnimator` or `AnimatorSet` to perform your animation. Only then you can turn off animations by turning off `Animator duration scale` in Developer options.

A good reference is the `ProgressBar`.

Comment: i added my device animation off setting screenshot. Even with these setting, the test still fail on animation.

Comment: Really important notice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/finn-no/android_emulator_hacks)

Build the project and download the generated .apk file and follow the instructions mentioned in that project to disable the animations and you should have a smooth sailing afterwards. You could also download the same .apk file from a lot of other sources.
Once you have the .apk file then issue the following commands:

```
adb install -r android_emulator_hacks.apk
adb shell pm grant no.finn.android_emulator_hacks android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE
adb shell am start -n no.finn.android_emulator_hacks/no.finn.android_emulator_hacks.HackActivity
```

This will take care of disabling the system animations for you.