# Espresso can't click displayed view

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, barista

Overnight my ui tests stopped working all of a sudden:

Line in barista `clickOn(R.id.myView)` throws:

```
com.schibsted.spain.barista.internal.failurehandler.BaristaException: Could not perform action single click on view with id: [...]   
[...]   
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (is displayed on the screen to the user and with id: [...]
```

Line in Espresso `onView(withId(R.id.myView)).perform(scrollTo(), click())` throws:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 53, 1723 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.  
[...]   
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
```

I don't understand why this happens. I can see the view on screen during the test and espresso gave me some coordinates.

**Edit:**
Since it's a TextView I also tried Baristas `clickOn(context.getString(R.string.myText))` but it throws:

```
com.schibsted.spain.barista.internal.failurehandler.BaristaException: Could not perform action single click on view with text: is [...]  
[...]   
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (is displayed on the screen to the user and with text: is [...]
```

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/myView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/myText"/>
```

Comment: Can you try again with Window / Transition Animation Scale set to Off? From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751079/espresso-testing-disable-animation)?

Comment: I did that, however it doesn't change anything. There are no layout changes or animations in this fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is unrelated to Espresso or Barista.
`java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty` was thrown in the `OnClickListener` of the view.